# Seeking for a different method to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{3^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have this limit I've been trying to solve, and so far I can only solve it using the property of geometric series.

So we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{3^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Is everything alright with this solution and is there any other way using the basic limit solving techniques to solve this limit?

Comment: You should multiply by a factor of $1/3^2$, since the closed-form of the geometric series starts at $n=0$.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, however.

Comment: @Integrand I see, many thanks. Well, the emphasis of my question was on the part where I ask for another way to solve the limit, not just the solution verification.

Comment: *is there any other way* --- If you were fluent with base $3$ numeration, then you'd recognize this as the repeating "decimal expansion" $0.0111\ldots,$ which is $1/3$ of $0.111\ldots,$ or $1/3$ of $1/2,$ which equals $1/6.$ Recall that in base $b,$ the "decimal expansion" $0.kkk\ldots$ is equal to $\frac{k}{b-1}$ (i.e. in base $10,$ we have $0.777\ldots = 7/9$ and $0.333\ldots = 3/9).$ But since you're Grigori Perelman, you probably already know this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{3^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{3}{2}$

This is not correct as $\sum_{n=\color{red}0}^{\infty} (\frac 13)^n = \frac 1{1-\frac 13}$ and $\sum_{n=\color{red}0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\ne\sum_{n=\color{red}2}^{\infty} (\frac 13)^n$.

But there are two ways to correct this:

1. $\sum_{n=\color{red}2}^{\infty} (\frac 13)^n = \sum_{k=\color{red}0}^{\infty} (\frac 13)^n  - \sum_{n=\color{red}0}^{\color{blue}1} (\frac 13)^n = [\frac 32] - [(\frac 13)^0 + (\frac 13)^1]= \frac 32 - \frac 43=\frac 16$
2. $\sum_{n=\color{red}2}^{\infty} (\frac 13)^n=\sum_{n=\color{red}2}^{\infty} [\color{blue}{\frac 1 {3^2}}(\frac 13)^{n\color{blue}{-2}}]=\frac 19\sum_{n=\color{red}2}^{\infty} (\frac 13)^{n\color{blue}{-2}}=\frac 19\sum_{\color{purple}{m=0}; (m=n-2)}^{\infty} (\frac 13)^m=\frac 19\cdot \frac32 = \frac 16$

I don't think there is any way to solve this in any way that doesn't reinvent the wheel and use geometric series.

But $\lim{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=2}^n (\frac 13)^k =\frac 16$ means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N_\epsilon$ so that for all $n>N_\epsilon$ then $|\frac 16 - \sum_{k=2}^n (\frac 13)^k| < \epsilon$.

Now we can prove by induction if $\sum_{k=2}^n (\frac 13)^k = x$ then $9x = \sum_{k=2}^n 9(\frac 13)^k=\sum_{k=2}^n (\frac 13)^{k-2}=\sum_{m=0}^{n-2}(\frac 13)^m$. And $9x(1-\frac 13)=(1-\frac 13)\sum_{m=0}^{n-2}(\frac 13)^m= 1-(\frac 13)^{n-1}$.  So $x = \frac {1-(\frac 13)^{n-1}}{9(1-\frac 13)}=\frac  {1-(\frac 13)^{n-1}}6$.

(In other words we just reinvented the wheel to derive the basic formula for finite sums of geometric series).

And we can use the standard $\epsilon$ proof to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1-(\frac 13)^{n-1}}6 = \frac 16$.

$|\frac 16 - \frac {1-(\frac 13)^{n-1}}6|=\frac 1{3\cdot 6^{n-1}}$ so if $n>\log_6{\frac 1{3\epsilon}}+1$ then $|\frac 16 -\sum_{k=2}^n(\frac 13)^k| < \epsilon$.

(In other words we just reinvented the wheel to derive the formula for converging infinite sums of geometric series.)

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\sum_{\color{red}{n=0}}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=1+\frac13+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{3^n}+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{3}{2}$$

therefore

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=\frac{3}{2}-1-\frac13=\frac16$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $S_n=1/9+1/27+...+1/3^n$, so our $r=1/3$, now $rS_n=1/27+1/81+....+1/3^{n+1}$, so $S_n-rS_n=1/9-1/3^{n+1}$ which implies $S_n=\frac{1/9-1/3^{n+1}}{1-r}$ and we then take the limit of $S_n$, so we have $S_n=\frac{1/9}{1-1/3}=1/6$.